# Haskell polymorphic type

Tags: haskell

I am working on an excercise but i don't know how to create the division function

```
-- defines data type with two constructors
data Expr = Val Int | Div Expr Expr

-- defines a function that turns an expression into an integer
-- eval :: Expr -> Int


-- eval (Div x y) = Div x * Div y
-- write an evaluation function for both Expr types
-- TODO eval (Val n) =
eval (Val n) = n


-- TODO eval (Div x y) =



-- now calculate 6 / 3 with the created function
-- TODO testeval =
testeval = eval (Div (Val 6) (Val 3))
```

Comment: Think recursively. `x` and `y` are both values of type `Expr`. Do you have a function of type `Expr -> Int`? Given two `Int` values, can you divide them to get another `Int`?

Comment: Also, this does not involved polymorphism. Rather, `expr` is a sum type, whose values are "tagged" as either being `Val`ues   or `Div`isions.

Comment: sorry still a newbie, cant figure it out, cant seem to get my head arround how i access the value in the function

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the first case:

```
eval (Val n) = n
```

By the definition of `Val`, `n` is an `Int`, so we simply return `n`. Then, for example, `eval (Val 3) == 3`, `eval (Val 10) == 10`, etc.

Now let's look at the second case.

```
eval (Div x y) = ???
```

By the definition of `Div` both `x` and `y` have type `Expr`, so we can't simply return one or the other, and we don't know how to do math on `Expr` values. But we *do* now how to do math on `Int` values:

```
> 6 `div` 3
2
```

and we know we can use `eval` to get an `Int` from an `Expr`:

```
> eval (Val 6)
6
```

So the first thing you need to do is use `eval` to evaluate both `x` and `y` to get their `Int` values. Once you have them, you can use `div` to produce the desired value.

```
> eval (Div (Val 6) (Val 3))
2
```